# How do I access an asset field in the 'onSaveEntry' event?

Tags: plugin-development, assets, events

I'm listening on an entries save event with:

```
craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
  //$event->params['entry']); -> passes to function 
});
```

How can I assess assets that are also part of that saved entry?

`$event->params['entry']->getContent()->{fieldname}` doesn't give me the array with information I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you an [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel):

```
$entryModel = $event->params['entry'];
```

This will give you an array of [AssetFileModels](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel):

```
$assetFileModels = $entryModel->myAssetFieldHandle
```

You can loop through them like so:

```
foreach ($assetFileModels as $assetFileModel)
{
    $url = $assetFileModel->getUrl();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about `$event->params['entry']->{fieldname}`

Wouldn't that be enough?